# How to avoid Google indexing specific app version on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, googlebot

I have a website deployed on gae. This resource has purchased a domain, but of course you can go to the site and a standard domain types app_id.appspot.com plus this can also go there and version_id.app_id.appspot.com. More than that if you enter abrakadabra.app_id.appspot.com get on Default version.

So google robot somehow found my version 1 and 2. For SEO is not very helpful :(. Plus all robots began to come to the site more often (increased load) quotas are spent quickly. Maybe someone has already encountered this problem, tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to create filter on url /robots.txt and send for versions hosts text like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*
```

Google crawler no more come to versioned hosts! :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

You might be able to specify a preferred domain in Google webmaster tools.  See:  http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&safe=on&answer=44231

Also, perhaps you could use canonical URLs to tell Google (and other search engines) which version to index.  See:  http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=gh96oax614pa&cbrank=0

(Note that there was a similar question on StackOverflow:  [appspot.com url shows up in google search results instead of custom domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315003/appspot-com-url-shows-up-in-google-search-results-instead-of-custom-domain-name) )

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now is:

```
public class VersionFilter implements Filter {
```

...

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String serverName = request.getServerName();

        if (serverName.contains("appspot.com") && !UserBean.isAdmin()) {
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            if (request.getParameter("login") != null) {
                UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
                httpResponse.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL("/"));
            } else if (request.getParameter("logout") != null) {
                UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
                httpResponse.sendRedirect(userService.createLogoutURL("/"));
            } else {
                httpResponse.sendError(403);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
    }
```

...
    }